# Cannot make a simple AppInsights Hello World work

Tags: azure, console-application, azure-application-insights

Consider the following simple program:

**Program.cs**

```
using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights;

namespace azure
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var tc = new TelemetryClient();
            tc.Context.InstrumentationKey = "***MY KEY IS HERE***";
            tc.TrackTrace("Hello World!");
            tc.Flush();
        }
    }
}
```

**packages.config**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights" version="2.5.1" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource" version="4.4.0" targetFramework="net452" />
</packages>
```

**App.config**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2" />
    </startup>
</configuration>
```

**azure.csproj**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="14.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props')" />
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
    <ProjectGuid>{2F7BE378-D37D-4297-AF97-4A9E771CF84C}</ProjectGuid>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <AppDesignerFolder>Properties</AppDesignerFolder>
    <RootNamespace>azure</RootNamespace>
    <AssemblyName>azure</AssemblyName>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.5.2</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    <FileAlignment>512</FileAlignment>
    <AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>true</AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
    <PlatformTarget>AnyCPU</PlatformTarget>
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <Optimize>false</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Debug\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
    <PlatformTarget>AnyCPU</PlatformTarget>
    <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Release\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights, Version=2.5.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.2.5.1\lib\net45\Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.dll</HintPath>
      <Private>True</Private>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System" />
    <Reference Include="System.Core" />
    <Reference Include="System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource, Version=4.0.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource.4.4.0\lib\net45\System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource.dll</HintPath>
      <Private>True</Private>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Xml.Linq" />
    <Reference Include="System.Data.DataSetExtensions" />
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.CSharp" />
    <Reference Include="System.Data" />
    <Reference Include="System.Net.Http" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xml" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="Program.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="App.config" />
    <None Include="packages.config" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
</Project>
```

I compile it in Visual Studio 2015.

It is supposed to send something to my Application Insights account, right? Yet I do not see anything.

Any ideas what is missing?

Comment: How about if you go to Analytics and query for all `traces`?

Comment: It is there. So, everything is alright, then?

Comment: Depends on what you were expecting :)

Comment: I was hoping to see something on the AppInsights page. I will try tracking some dummy event next. Please, arrange your comment as the answer so I could credit you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to prevent losing telemetry events with Application Insight's Persistence Channel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33239928/how-to-prevent-losing-telemetry-events-with-application-insights-persistence-ch)

Comment: it appears from the comments that you don't actually have a problem, you just weren't looking in the right place in the portal for your data?  if so, you might want to answer your own question. so the rest of us don't spend time investigating an already resolved thing :)

Comment: it could be a mix of both.I am very new to this. From the suggested post it is not clear to me what is the right approach. Should I use in-memory channel (have to learn what it is) for all of my events? I do not have a dedicated shutdown event.

Answer (score 1):

if you debug this, and put a breakpoint before the app ends, do you see output in the console from application insights?

the problem is *probably* that your process ends before anything has time to start up outbound http and actually *send* your data.

the flush method is not synchronous, the app isn't waiting for it to send before terminating.

an old but possibly relevant related question: 
[How to prevent losing telemetry events with Application Insight's Persistence Channel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33239928/how-to-prevent-losing-telemetry-events-with-application-insights-persistence-ch)

Answer (score 0):

If you add the ApplicationInsight nuget to your project, it will set everything up for you, including creating the applicationinsights.config file.

Just make sure you set your telemetry key to your Application Insight account.

```
<ApplicationInsights xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ApplicationInsights/2013/Settings">
  <InstrumentationKey>{YOUR GUID HERE}</InstrumentationKey>
...
</ApplicationInsights>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting instrumentation key to the telemetry client context, try setting the key to TelemetryConfiguration.

TelemetryConfiguration.Active.InstrumentationKey = {telemetryInstrumentationId};

You can multiple instances of telemetry client, so instead of setting the key on each instance..set the key to configuration which will be used by all instances.